# Registration form, recommendations for shared entities?

Tags: account-management, user-interface, registration

I have a web app, that teachers will be registering for, the registration form has school name, school website.

So, I will have data redundant filling the school name each time for teachers at the same school.

What's the recommended approach to solve this issue ? 
is it a good idea to tell teacher to fill his school data in a separate form ? (might leave the page ) so that he will choose it from a drop list field at the main registration form ? 
is it a good idea to let teacher enter his school data ?

What's the recommended approach to have a good user experience ?

**Edit**
this question is not technical, stackoverflow is for coding and pure technical questions, I am asking about good user experience, so why to close it ?

Comment: You may have more luck asking that on stackoverflow.com

Comment: this question is not technical, stackoverflow is for coding and pure technical questions, I am asking about good user experience

Comment: You should try [ux.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be good for the user to be able to choose his school from a list. Only if the school is not yet there, ask the user to create new school.

Are you saving school info for each teacher separately, or do you want to have separate list of schools without duplicates?

Second approach however will not stop a teacher from creating second entry for the same school with different data, or incomplete entries. That would have to be merged manually by moderator or something.

Comment: I will have one table for all schools, so that each school' data get entered only one time, but, is it good to let teacher leave the registration form, to enter his school data in another form ?

Comment: This depends, at which point you save your data to DB and if you can have teacher record with no associated school record. Always remember, that it may and will happen, that user closes another form before saving data or looses internet connection.